# C# web reference -setting the Timeout in app.config

Tags: c#, timeout, web-reference

I have a program that uses web reference in order to connect to the server. 
The web reference is configured in app.config file in the following way:

```
   <applicationSettings>
        <blala.Properties.Settings>
          <setting name="blablaClient_AppexScan_Service1" serializeAs="String">
            <value>http://www.apex.com/CxWS/Service1.asmx</value>
          </setting>
        </blabla.Properties.Settings>
  <applicationSettings>
```

I would like to add to the setting a property of Timeout.
I would like to change the default timeout from 100000 msec to something else
and I would like to do it in the app.config.

when I tried to add:

```
<setting name="Timeout" serializeAs="String">

       <value>30</value>

</setting>
```

it didn't change the default timeout.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Adjust the proxy of your web service

```
var timeout = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Timeout"];

WebReference.ProxyClass myProxy = new WebReference.ProxyClass();
myProxy.Timeout = timeout;
```

Comment: how can I do it only in the app.config file?

Comment: try with <webServices><soapEnvelopeProcessing readTimeout=""/>

</webServices>

Comment: It's a web-reference not a web web service. I'm talking about the client, not the server side

Comment: ok i inderstand your environment, let me small time in order to find, because i had this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the timeout after initialising your web services.

```
WSName.WSClass refWS = WSMng.Initialize(ServerName, ServerPort, ServerInstance, ServerCompanyName);
refWS.Timeout = 200000;
```